# Chrome inspect element content by code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a code that reads through webpage source code and get data.

The webpage source code is kind of protected. I could get the data through Chrome inspect element, and copy the body as element and save as html file. Then I could get the data I want with no problem.

The only thing that I could not manage do to in code is how to get the inspect element content by code.

Comment: why the `java` tag?

Comment: Unclear how you are supposed to be reading it by code.... Where does the code run that is reading the page's content?

Comment: *"The webpage source code is kind of protected."* How? If the webpage is online then the source code isn't protected at all..its just a HTTP request away really.

Comment: I believe it is javascript thing, when I run curl or even I open the webpage source manually, I dont see the data I need I have to inspect element by Chrome and copy the body as element.

Answer (score 1):

So.. i don't really understand what you mean but perhaps curl is what you are looking for?

something like:

```
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page > test.html
```

will give you a file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>
<script>document.documentElement.className...
```

Then you can do whatever you want to it.
Hope this helps?

if you are using a machine which doesn't have curl:
https://curl.haxx.se/

```
//with chocolatey
choco install curl

//with apt
apt install curl
```

Comment: curl command gives the webpage source which does not have the information I want. what I need is only accessible when I inspect element by Chrome and copy the body as element then save it in html file.

Comment: What exactly do you think the inspect element is getting you that is not in the source code of the page?